# R order a table for barplot by predefined settings

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I have a table that looks like this:

```
cos_table<-table(df$COS) #simply count the frequency of COS in the table
```

> ```
> A     B      C     D   
> 2880  6001   834  2833
> ```

When I plot it with `barplot(cos_table)` I get a bar plot with the order of A B C D

My request is to organize the barplot with a different order: A D C B (it make sense for the end users). Q: How can I organize a table in such way that I choose the order?

Comment: Before running `table` do this: `df$COS = factor(df$COS, levels=c("A","D","C","B"))`.

Comment: @eipi10 yes - this does the trick. Write it as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the categories in the desired order by converting `COS` to a `factor`:

```
df$COS = factor(df$COS, levels=c("A","D","C","B"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
barplot(cos_table[c("A","D","C","B")])
```

If you want to avoid factors.